# How do I ignore pdf links while scraping using Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm new to Scrapy and I'm currently making a spider that extracts only the event title and event description from a website. I am able to get the title and description, however, the spider is also trying to extract data from a pdf link which causes a "raise NotSupported("Response content isn't text")" error. How can I prevent the spider from doing this?

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

class EventsspiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'eventsspider'
    allowed_domains =['cs.acadiau.ca']
    start_urls = ['https://cs.acadiau.ca/news-events/event-reader/using-dna-to-reverse-engineer-your-family-tree.html']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('news-events/event-reader/using-dna-to-reverse-engineer-your-family-tree.html', )), callback='parse_item', follow=True),)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        i = {}

        title_list = response.xpath('//*[@id="event-items-15421"]/div[2]/div/h1/text()').extract()
        data_list = response.xpath('//*[@id="event-items-15421"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/p[7]/span/text()').extract()

        for x in range(0, len(title_list)):
            i['title'] = title_list[x]
            i['data'] = data_list[x]
            yield i
```

Comment: @Prune when you say main program, do you mean my pipelines.py file?

Comment: You'd need to modify your rules to change what links are followed. But it looks like you're only scraping a single link (and your rule is weird), so why are you using a `CrawlSpider`?

Comment: @Prune a spider class is all you need. `scrapy runspider filename.py` is one possible way to run it.

Comment: @Prune at the moment I'm using the command `scrapy crawl spidername` to execute the code and see it's output in my terminal.

Comment: @stranac My aim in the end is to crawl multiple links with the same html. I'm just using a single link right now to see if my xpaths work and it does except once my spider extracts the data it tries to extract the same data from (https://cs.acadiau.ca/news-events/event-reader/using-dna-to-reverse-engineer-your-family-tree.html?pdf=15421) which causes the error I mentioned in my question. Would regex and the deny rule help solve my problem?

Comment: Thanks for the command-line clarifications; I withdraw my objection as unfounded.  Comment deleted.

Comment: Now ... where are you stuck in writing a simple expression to exclude links with `.pdf` at the end?  Is there a stage of the crawling that isn't under your control?

Comment: @Prune after the spider gets the data I want, instead of closing, it tries to extract data from a pdf link, (https://cs.acadiau.ca/news-events/event-reader/using-dna-to-reverse-engineer-your-family-tree.html?pdf=15421). I've been looking for a way to prevent this but so far I can't find anything on how to do it.

Comment: As per the scrapy documentation ".pdf" is excluded by default, (https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/linkextractors/__init__.py. )You can also try explicitly adding a deny_extensions to your linkextractor rule, here is the reference (https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml.LxmlLinkExtractor)